# React Passing Props through Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a Portfolio Component which will pass through an array of strings for image sources to a component called Piece. The piece will represent each piece of work I have worked on and display four images which will be sent from the portfolio.

Portfolio renders: `<Piece examples = {cars} image = "images/icons/laptop-cars.png" title = "Project Car" />` Cars is the name of the array which has image sources.

As Piece will have a gallery of images, I also have created a component called Gallery. I am trying to pass the array from Portfolio to Gallery but this won't work for me.

In Piece, I render: `let images = this.props.examples;` and return

In Gallery, I have `let images = this.props.images` again and I then try to return the array by saying: 
`</div>
     {images.map(each => <img src = {each} alt = "" width = "300px"/>)}
</div>`

This displays an error where it says images is undefined in the Gallery component.

Can anyone tell me how to have Piece pass through this as a prop to Gallery correctly?

Thanks.

**Props:**

```
export default class Piece extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isClicked: false
        };
        this.toggleGallery = this.toggleGallery.bind(this);
    }
    toggleGallery() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            isClicked: !state.isClicked
        }));
    }
    render() {
        let images = this.props.examples;
        return(
            <div id = "piece">
                <div id = "piece-container">
                    <div id = "details">
                        <div id = "piece-image">
                            <img src={this.props.image} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div id = "work-description">
                            <h2> {this.props.title}</h2>
                            <p> {this.props.description}</p>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div id = "link">
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleGallery}> Please click here to view examples of this work. </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = {this.state.isClicked ? "car-gallery" : "hidden"}>
                    <Gallery imageArray = {images} link = "link to source"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Gallery:**

```
export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
    render() {
      let images = this.props.imageArray;
      return (
        <div className="gallery-container">
           <div id = "link" >
           <a target="_blank" href={this.props.link}>Click here to see a live version</a>
           </div>
          {images.map(each => <img src = {each} alt = "" width = "300px"/>)}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

**Portfolio:**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import Piece from '../Piece/Piece';

const array1= [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg",
    "image4.jpg"
];

const array2= [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg",
    "image4.jpg"
];

export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id = "portfolio">
                <h1> Please find below some examples of my work</h1>
               <Piece examples = {array1} image = "image of piece" title = "Title of piece." />

                <Piece examples = {array2} image = "image of piece" title = "Title of piece." />

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code of `Piece` and `Gallery` ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 edited now sorry

Comment: The constructor of `Gallery` has no `props` passed - try by doing like in `Piece`.

Comment: The constructor of Gallery is missing props. It is best to remove the constructor is you don't need a special logic there.

Comment: @moonwave99 I have added props to the constructor like in Piece but it still gives the same error. Removing the constructor completely also still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the Portfolio component? This is the root component, right? Who is passing examples to `Piece` component?

Comment: @faboulaws have added the Portfolio now.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Does your actual code have all the spaces between the attributes and the curly brackets? I recommend you remove them and see if it works then.

Comment: Please setup a stackblitz

Comment: I was doing something really stupid in my Portfolio component that meant it was always breaking and turns out my code was working all this time guys. Thanks so much for helping though!